# repeating for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I want to count from 0 to 199 three times in a row in 10 millisecond steps like  0 1 2 ... 198 199 0 1 2 .... 198 199 0 1 2 .... The first run is working fine with:

```
function count() {
    time = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        time += 10;
        setTimeout(function(j) {
            return function() {
                console.log(j);
            }
        }(i), time);
    };
};

count();
```

but i do not get the desired result when calling the function three times like

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  count();
}
```

What is the right way for me?

Comment: Should ``animateRio();`` be ``count();``?

Comment: what   animateRio() refers to ?

Comment: I cant find the thread that describes this correctly but I believe its because the settimeout in your count() is non-blocking so the for-loop will continue to run without the time delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that should be timed too:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(animateRio /*or do you mean count?*/, i*2000);
}
```

Comment: i mean "count". Sorry! I will try the nested timeout.

Comment: it is not working. the console gives each number from 0 to 199 three times at the same time

Comment: now it is working fine. i used "count()" instead of just "count". Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to schedule all of your own timeouts, setInterval can call a function every unit of time. So create an interval that will run every 10 milliseconds. Then add a loop counter and use some modulo arithmetic.

```
var time = -1, 
   interval, 
   loop = 3; 

interval = setInterval(function() {
    time += 1;

    if(time % 200 === 0) {
        loop--;
    }

    if(loop < 0){
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
    }    
    console.log(time % 200);
}, 10);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2t6wjnp4/2/)